# setErrorByName not working properly if field is in #details

Tags: 8, forms

In a form, some fields are defined in '#details':

```
$form['person2'] = [
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => t('Person2'),
];
$form['person2']['lastname2'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Last Name'),
  '#size' => 32,
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('lastname2') ? $this->store->get('lastname2') : '',
];
$form['person2']['firstname2'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('First Name'),
  '#size' => 32,
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('firstname2') ? $this->store->get('firstname2') : '',
];
$form['person2']['email2'] = [
  '#type' => 'email',
  '#title' => $this->t('Email'),
  '#size' => 64,
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('email2') ? $this->store->get('email2') : '',
  '#weight' => $weight,
];
```

In `validateForm()` I have some controls: if one of the fields has a value, the others should have one too.
I use `setErrorByName` but I can't have the faulty field highlighted in red, though the control fires as expected...
Here is the code:

```
  if (!$form_state->getValue('firstname2')) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('lastname2', $this->t('This field is required.'));
  }
```

Comment: Try something like `$form_state->setErrorByName('[person2][firstname]', $this->t('This field is required.'));` as your field is a child of a container you need to specify the container in the name

Comment: It seems it is more a CSS thing: in the theme used for my site, there are no `.form-item input.error` definition... When I add it, it works.

Comment: @Leigh Might be wrong, but I think you exclude the leading/trailing bracket for that pattern? e.g. `'person2][firstname'`

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Clive in comment is the correct one.

```
$form_state->setErrorByName('person2][lastname2', $this->t('This field is required.'));
```

Though if you just want to make the field required it would be better to do:

```
$form['person2']['lastname2'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Last Name'),
  '#size' => 32,
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('lastname2') ? $this->store->get('lastname2') : '',
  '#required' => true,
];
```